# When is data ready for querying in Google BigQuery after a Load Job?

Tags: google-bigquery

Say I have a very large CSV file that I'm loading to a bigquery table. Will this data be available for querying only after the whole file has been uploaded and the job is finnished or will it be available for querying as as the file is being uploaded?

Comment: The data will be available to query when the **load job** is done.

Comment: promote comment to answer please @YunZhang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery will commit data from a load job in an all-or-none fashion.  Partial results will not appear in the destination table as a job is progessing, results are committed at the end of the load job.

A load job that terminates with an error will commit no rows.  However, for use cases where you have poorly sanitized data, you can optionally choose to configure your load job to allow bad/malformed data to be ignored through configuration values like MaxBadRecords.  In such cases, a job may have warnings and still commit the successfully processed data, but the commit semantics remain the same (all at the end, or none if the defined threshold for bad data is exceeded).